# Property 'aboutData' does not exist on type 'never[]'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework

What is the best way to print array items? It's return error "Property 'post_title' does not exist on type 'never[]'".

How to use interface to define these variables and use them in code for both aboutData and executive array items.

API resoponse

```
{
    "aboutData": {
        "post_id": 18,
        "post_title": "Established since 2014",
    },
    "executive": [
        {
            "post_id": 39,
            "post_title": "Quality and excellence in everything we do.",
        },
    ],
}
```

Here is the component file:

```
const About: React.FC = () => {

    const history = useHistory();
    const [showLoading, setShowLoading] = useState(true);
    const { authValues, setAuthValues } = React.useContext(userContext);
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        getAbout();
    }, []);

    const getAbout = async () => {
        setShowLoading(true);

        return api
            .getabout()
            .then((response) => {
                setData(response.data.data);
                console.log(response.data.data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    };    

    return (
        <IonPage>

      <IonContent fullscreen>
        <IonCard>
          <IonCardContent>
            <IonList className="dash_grid">
               <IonItem>
              <IonLabel>{data.aboutData.post_title}</IonLabel>
              </IonItem>
            </IonList>
            <IonList color="primary" className="history_box">
              {data.executive.length > 0 ? (
                data.executive.map((exec) => {
                  return (
                    <IonItem>
                        <IonText color="medium">{exec.post_title}</IonText>
                    </IonItem>
                  );
                })
              ) : null}
            </IonList>
          </IonCardContent>
        </IonCard>
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
    );
};

export default About;
```

Comment: according to your default value  `data` is an array and not an object

Answer (score 0):

You should add optional chaining when using map "?". Add it after data.

```
  {data?.executive.length > 0 ? (
            data?.executive.map((exec) => {
```

Comment: It's giving same error Property 'executive' does not exist on type 'never[]'

Answer (score 0):

You inited your `data` in the wrong way. That was not an array. Change into this

> ```
>     const [data, setData] = useState(null);
>     ...
>     if(!data) return null; // you can handle the loading page here when data is not ready yet
>
>     return (
>         ...
>     )
> ```

Comment: It say Object is possibly 'null' in {data.aboutData.post_title}

Comment: try this: data?.aboutData?.post_title

Comment: Property 'aboutData' does not exist on type '{}'. I am getting values in console.log(data.aboutData.post_title); but when print inside code it's giving error

Comment: Then `data` will be typed as `null` which is not nearly as useful.

Answer (score 0):

`[]` in TypeScript is **automatically** inferred as `never[]`:

```
    const [data, setData] = useState([]); // useState<never[]>([]);
    //                               ^^  never[]
```

So you have to tell TypeScript that it's not (and thankfully useState accepts a generic):

```
    const [data, setData] = useState<{ post_id: number; post_title: string }>([]); // good
```

But for readability too, use an interface:

```
interface PostData { post_id: number; post_title: string }

const [data, setData] = useState<PostData[]>([]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting an object according of the API response, you need to initialize the useState({}) with an empty object instead of an array

```
const [data, setData] = useState({});
```

Then you'll have to check if the object has the properties you are expecting in this line:

```
 <IonLabel>{data?.aboutData?.post_title}</IonLabel>
```

you can use optional chaining for this part.
And also for this line, take care of the properties

```
 {data?.executive?.length > 0 ? (
```

Depends on what your trying to do, I'd recommend you to paint the list conditionally depending on the data content.